# Testing Credit Usage in Wolfram Programming Cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I currently have a free WPC account, which I am using for testing purposes.  Amongst other things, I want to find out more about how the credit system works, in particular how many credits are used, based on various different operations.

However, whenever I try to access the Usage Summary Report in my WPC account I receive the following, unhelpful error message:

"Sorry you do not have permission to access this item. Try using a different account."

Are free WPC accounts not provisioned with access to usage reports?  How does one budget credit usage without such information?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem.  Might it be an issue with your browser cache or some other account login effect?

Comment: Although this is of general interest to visitors to this site, please bear in mind that we are just users like you, and have no special knowledge of how WRI charges for services. I'd suggest seeking an answer from WRI directly and then posting the response as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 8):

It turns out to be a simple issue of geography:  if your userid is registered in one geographic location, WPC appears unable to produce reports if accessed from a different geographic location.  Rather counter-intuitive for a cloud service, I would say.

Answer (score 8):

It is not a secret how many credits are used by a certain type of operation:

[image: Wolfram credits]

This information is available [here](http://www.wolfram.com/cloud-credits/).

Comment: A belated congratulations on reaching 10K "reputation."  Thank you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you :)